# Reserved Keyword search, but in reverse. Regex

Tags: regex, keyword

I'm writing a code that looks through a string and then takes in words that are not considered "reserved keywords". I am new to regex, but have spent quite some time learning what kind of structure I need to look for reserved words. So far, I've written something along the lines of this:

```
\b(import|false|int|etc)\b
```

I am going to use an array list to feed in all of the reserved words into the string above, but I need it to work opposite of how it works now. I've figured out how to get it to search for the specific words with the code above, but how can I get it to look for the words that are NOT listed above. I've tried incorporating the `^` symbol, but I'm not having any luck there. Any regex veterans out there who see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious possibilities, depending on what (else) you are doing.

**Possibility 1: Use a `dict` or `set`:**

You could just match *words* and then test for membership in a set or dictionary:

```
Reserved_words = set('import false true int ...'.split())

word_rx = r'\b\w+\b'   # Or whatever rule you like for "words"

for m in re.finditer(...):
    word = m.group(0)
    if word in Reserved_words:
        print("Found reserved word:", word)
    else:
        print("Found unreserved word:", word)
```

This approach is frequently used in lexers, where it is easier to just write a catch-all "match a word" rule, and then check a matched word against a list of keywords, than it is to write a fairly complex rule for each keyword and a catch-all to deal with the rest.

You can use a `dict` if you want to associate some kind of payload with the keyword (such as a class handle for instantiating a particular AST node type, etc.).

**Possibility 2: Use named groups:**

Another possibility is that you could use [*named groups*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#regular-expression-syntax) in your regex to capture keyword/nonkeyword values:

```
word_rx = r'\b(?<keyword>import|int|true|false|\.\.\.)|(?<nonkeyword>\w+)\b'

for m in re.finditer(...):
    word = m.group('keyword')
    if word:
        print("Found keyword:", word)
    else:
        word = m.group('nonkeyword')
        print("Found nonkeyword:", word)
```

This is going to be slower than the previous approach, because of prefixes: "int" matches a keyword, but "integral" starts to match an int, then fails, then backtracks to the other branch, then matches a nonkeyword. :-(

However, if you are strongly tied to a mostly-regex implementation, for example, if you have many other regex-based rules, and you are processing them in a loop, then go for it!